# Наследование полей и методов

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, методы, имена

```
class a{
public:
int y;
void f(){cout<<6;}
};

class b: public a{
public: 
int y;
void f(){cout<<7;}
};
```

Почему можно делать функции и переменные с одинаковыми именами, как у родительского класса? То есть почему в наследнике не возникает конфликт имен, ведь в нем присутствуют уже все эти методы и поля родительского?

Comment: Просто язык так сделан. К родительскому полю/методу можно обратиться даже при таком конфликте: `b obj; obj.a::y = 42;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имя некоторой сущности — того же члена `y`, как просто `y` — это сокращенная форма, когда очевиден контекст. На самом деле используется *полностью квалифицированное имя*, которое включает то, к какому классу и какому объекту оно относится. Вас ведь совершенно не смущает, что могут быть два объекта одного класса с одинаковыми членами? потому что вы не используете имя члена само по себе, а присовокупляете к нему имя объекта или указатель на него.

Так и в вашем примере полное имя включает имя класса. При этом в классе-потомке происходит сокрытие имени из предка, в том смысле, что обращение по короткому имени `y` приводит к обращению к члену в текущем контексте, члену класса-потомка.

Могут быть достаточно закрученные наследования, когда придется указывать в имени не один класс. Например, в приведенном ниже примере с множественным наследованием для обращения к члену `A` надо указать, к члену какого именно `A`  обращение :)

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    void out() { cout << x << endl; }
};

struct B: public A
{
    int x;
    void out() { cout << x << endl; }
};

struct C: public A
{
    int x;
    void out() { cout << x << endl; }
};

struct D: public B, public C
{
    int x;
    void out() { cout << x << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    D d;
    d.C::x = 0;
    d.B::x = 1;
    d.C::A::x = 2;
    d.B::A::x = 3;


    d.B::A::out();
    d.C::A::out();
    d.B::out();
    d.C::out();

}
```

P.S. Ау, гуру стандартов! Обнаружил, что приведенный выше код на ура компилируется Visual C++, но не хочет компилироваться, например, G++. Кто неправ? Лично я никакой неоднозначности не вижу — полностью квалифицированные имена различны, какая уж тут неоднозначность?...