# Неоднозначность при множественном наследовании

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, множественное-наследование, имена

Отвечал на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1553083/) об одинаковых именах при наследовании. Написал такой код (см. ниже). Visual C++ его компилирует и выполняет на ура. Но масса прочих компиляторов ругается на

```
d.C::A::x = 2;
d.B::A::x = 3;
```

и вызовы `out()`, утверждая, что тут неоднозначность в выборе `A::x`. Откровенно говоря, я ее не вижу; вывод у VC++ соответствует ожидаемому.

Кто-то может доказать правоту того или иного компилятора ***явной ссылкой на пункт стандарта***? Откуда тут неоднозначность — при явном указании пути через `B` или `C`? Как ее устранить в таких компиляторах, кто недоволен?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A
{
    int x;
    void out() { cout << x << endl; }
};
struct B: public A
{
    int x;
    void out() { cout << x << endl; }
};
struct C: public A
{
    int x;
    void out() { cout << x << endl; }
};
struct D: public B, public C
{
    int x;
    void out() { cout << x << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.C::x = 0;
    d.B::x = 1;
    d.C::A::x = 2;  // неоднозначность в не-MSVC
    d.B::A::x = 3;  // неоднозначность в не-MSVC

    d.B::A::out();  // неоднозначность в не-MSVC
    d.C::A::out();  // неоднозначность в не-MSVC
    d.B::out();
    d.C::out();
}
```

Comment: Не знаю что там по стандарту, но предполагаю, что компилятор не может понять, какой из 2х подъобъектов класса А здесь нужен. Помогает преобразование к ссылке/указателю на конкретный базовый класс: `static_cast<C*>(&d)->A::x = 2;`.

Comment: OFFTOP: у VS очень много непереносимого поведения: приходится  помучиться с компиляцией правкой кода под *nix

Comment: Странно, что не может: ему четко указано, как именно обращаться к члену A — через С или через B. За идею переделки кода — спасибо!

Comment: Запись `C::A` не имеет смысла. В пространстве имен `C` нет имени `A`. Компилятор VC фантазирует.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ОК, тогда почему в таком варианте https://ideone.com/NfGMf2 она имеет смысл?

Comment: Потому что я ошибся. Квалификация к имени базового класса есть. Нужна для доступа к скрытым при наследовании членам.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648905/scope-operator-for-base-class-in-super-multiple-non-virtual-inheritance

Comment: @Harry, https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf `$11.8 [class.member.lookup]`, 11й пункт - вроде бы оно.

Comment: @MaximTimakov Не согласен, там несколько иное, приведение указателя на потомка к указателю на предка (каковых два одинакового типа).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Как-то оно у них неоднозначно :) И, увы, без точной ссылки на стандарт...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда вы пишете `B::A` (причем неважно, что это после `.` - работает везде одинаково) - это то же самое, что просто `A` (если `B` - наследник `A`), поэтому `d.C::A::x` превращается в `d.A::x` - а это явно неоднозначность и ошибка.

- Почему `B::A` - то же самое, что `A`?

  Из-за *injected-class-name*. Injected-class-name - это что-то вроде скрытого `using ИмяКласса = ИмяКласса;`, который создается автоматически в каждом классе, и наследуется точно так же, как и все остальные члены класса.

  То есть `B` наследует из `A` что-то вроде `using A = A;`, поэтому `B::A` означает `A`.

  <sup>(Из этого также должно следовать, что `A::A` означает `A`, но вот это уже работает не везде: `struct B : A::A {};` работает, а `A::A a;` уже не работает - из-за [`[class.qual]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual#class.qual-1) (во втором случае компилятор считает `A::A` именем конструктора `A` - как при наследовании конструктора - `using A::A;`).)</sup>
- Как это `::` справа от `.` работает по тем же правилам, что и в любом другом месте? Ведь казалось бы, `A::x` (где `x` - нестатический член) работает только после `.`!

  А вот и нет, `A::x` для нестатических членов [работает много где](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#general-3). Везде, где результат выражения не вычисляется, например в `sizeof` и `decltype`:

  ```cpp
  #include <type_traits>

  struct A {int x;};

  static_assert(sizeof(A::x) == sizeof(int));
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(A::x), int>);
  ```

  А как вам такое:

  ```
  static_assert(sizeof(A::x + 42) == sizeof(int));
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(A::x + 42), int>);
  ```

В целом, в стандарте нигде не описывается поведение `::` конкретно справа от `.` Он работает везде одинаково. То есть нет никакого процесса "последовательного захода в родителей родителей"; единственная причина, почему у вас получилось указать нескольких родителей после в `d.C::A::x` - это injected-class-name.

Явно про ваш случай говорит [`[expr.ref]/7`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#7):

> [в выражении вида `E1.E2`...]
>
> If `E2` is a non-static member, the program is ill-formed if the class of which `E2` is directly a member is an ambiguous base ([class.member.lookup]) of the naming class ([class.access.base]) of `E2`.

Здесь "naming class" ("именующий/называющий/обращающийся класс"?) - это тип объекта слева от точки.

---

Есть другой способ обратиться к полю родителя - кастануть объект в ссылку на родителя:

```
static_cast<A &>(static_cast<C &>(d)).x
```

Или так:

```
static_cast<C &>(d).A::x
```

Comment: Мда... спорить трудно, *"закон есть закон!" (с) Ф.Пасторелли*, но все же точка зрения VC++ мне больше по душе :)

Comment: @Harry Ага, я когда вопрос прочитал, не поверил, что это ошибка. А оно вона как... :)